# SublimeText key binding for "Save Project as"?

Tags: sublimetext3

SublimeText is a customizable Text Editor. With default settings there is currently no key map bind to "Project/Save Project as" (v3.2.1).

How can I provide a key map for this command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `View Package File` from the command palette and open `Default/Main.sublime-menu` to view the definition of the main menu, you can search for the menu item caption and locate the command you're after:

```
  ...
  { "caption": "-" },
  { "command": "save_project_and_workspace_as", "caption": "Save Project As…", "mnemonic": "A" },
  { "command": "close_workspace", "caption": "Close Project", "mnemonic": "C" },
  { "command": "open_file", "args": {"file": "${project}"}, "caption": "Edit Project" },
  { "caption": "-" },
  { "command": "new_window_for_project", "caption": "New Workspace for Project" },
  { "command": "save_workspace_as", "caption": "Save Workspace As…", "mnemonic": "A" },
  { "caption": "-" },
  { "command": "prompt_add_folder", "caption": "Add Folder to Project…", "mnemonic": "d" },
  { "command": "close_folder_list", "caption": "Remove all Folders from Project", "mnemonic": "m" },
  { "command": "refresh_folder_list", "caption": "Refresh Folders", "mnemonic": "e" },
  ...
```

Armed with the command `save_project_and_workspace_as`, you can use `Preferences > Key Bindings` and bind it to any key you want; for example:

```
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+shift+p"],
    "command": "save_project_and_workspace_as",
}
```